# virtualenvwrapper mkproject and shell startup in windows issue?

Tags: python, windows-10, virtualenvwrapper

Why is the virtualenvwrapper mkproject command is not working in Windows 10?  And what file do you edit for shell startup in Windows 10 to setup virtualenvwrapper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is the virtualenvwrapper mkproject command is not working in Windows 10?

Because `virtualenvwrapper-win` is not an exact clone of `virtualenvwrapper` it's a different implementation of the same idea, nothing more.

See https://github.com/davidmarble/virtualenvwrapper-win/blob/master/README.rst#main-commands:

Use option `-a project_path` for `mkvirtualenv` command or `setprojectdir` command.

Answer (score 0):

`mkproject` is included in v1.2.4 of `virtualenvwrapper-win`.

There is no need to call a setup script like you would do in linux. The linux version implements virtualenvwrapper as shell functions, while virtualenvwrapper-win implements them as `.bat` files located in your python's Scripts directory.